# python multiprocess: parent process can not exit

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want parent process exit, and child process can still run.
When i run code,  parent process can not exit. I use `return` to exit parent process. And child process can still run.
Why did  parent process not exit?

**System: centos7**
**Python version: 3.6**

```
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def run_process():
    count = 0
    while True:
        print('it is son', os.getpid())
        time.sleep(3)
        count += 1
        if count >= 10:
            return


def main():
    t = Process(target=run_process)
    t.start()
    print('it is father', os.getpid())
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this happens because `multiprocessing` registering `atexit` handler.

[source1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b045cdaf341f80b7d1e4804b932b6e415600c2e1/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#L362) - registering in `util` module

[source2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b045cdaf341f80b7d1e4804b932b6e415600c2e1/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L291) - `util` module import

Probably you'd better use simple `os.fork` for your purposes.